# How to check if a text variable is contained within another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

just wondering how I can check to see if a text variable is contained within another variable. like

```
 var A = "J";

 var B = "another J";
```

something like :contains but for variables.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript itself has a function for this: indexOf.

```
alert("blaat".indexOf('a') != -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you want to find whether the contents of A are in B, just use the following:

```
var found = !(B.indexOf(A) == -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if one string belongs into another? 
You can use regular expresions or [strpos](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/javascript_equivalent_for_phps_strpos/) like function

```
function strpos( haystack, needle, offset){
    var i = (haystack+'').indexOf(needle, (offset ? offset : 0));
    return i === -1 ? false : i;
}
```

To my knowledge jQuery doesn't have a native function for doing what you want.